# webdriver : sendkeys & click sometimes fails

Tags: input, webdriver, sendkeys

Luckily  not so often but sometimes I noted that login to my application fails because it seems that `sendkeys` is not recognized at all .
Basically, I have two input objects  (usr/pwd ) and a SUBMIT button. 
I send usr/pwd to input objects and click SUBMIT but , from the screenshot I receive, these objects are empty after sendkeys , no errors happen after clicking  on SUBMIT ( a warning should be displayed)

Any idea?

Code looks like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[contains(@name,'username')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[contains(@name,'username')]")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[contains(@name,'username')]")).sendKeys("USENAME");
```

Comment: "login to my application fails" -- is any exception thrown? Try to add some delay before you enter login and password. In most of cases it solves the problem.

Comment: No exceptions at all. I have already delays but the problem is still there :-(

Comment: Would you be able to paste the html code of the page?